# C# Unity Sharing Class Instances VS Many Instances: Which is best performance?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on an Ability system for a rpg game in Unity.

I have decided I was going to have an Ability system made of `Ability` class instances which each contain an array of `Effect`s.

On an ability use a `Use()` method on the `Ability` is called which loops through the `Effect[]` array and calls an `Apply()` method on each.

The way I see it is that I will have to make sure that each effect can fetch the information it needs and store it in variables on its own class, as I cannot pass specific arguments to effects via the `Apply()` > `Use()` calls.

Assuming that I can find a way to do that, would it be more efficient to have only one instance of each `Effect` shared amongst all the Abilities or separate instances.

I can see drawbacks for both:

1) What I would expect is that with shared instances the `Use()` calls would have to be queued (am I right in thinking that ?) which could slow the game down when many calls are made.

2) With individual instances, I would not have that problem but I would constantly have a lot more instances loaded in memory.

Which is best ? In terms of general programming practice and performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually in a similar situation and thought I would share some of my thoughts.

I don't think that using a Use() function would really slow anything down, as the same basic code is going to have to be run in either implementation, and I don't think that a queue would be necessary, as you could make the functions static, not requiring any instances of the class to call the class methods.

I think the answer mainly depends on what kind of information you need passed into the Use() function. If each character needs to store parameters specific to each ability, then having individual instances won't really save memory, it just changes how the memory is organized, so I would go for individual instances for ease of use. If all the parameters are character specific rather than ability specific, then I think the other implementation would be the better one for memory, as you would only need to store something to point you to the proper Use() function.

I hope this helps! I don't really know that this the type of answer you were looking for, but I figured it's better than no answer. I would love to know what you choose to use!

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. So far only my player uses abilities so I can just make one instance of each ability and use that. I actually figured I was having more issues recycling my Effects system to use with things like equipment and consumables. I settled for overloads of the `Apply()` methods on the Effects. One takes in `Ability` the other `Consumable`. In the future I might pass the character GameObject of the character using the ability to the `Use()` method.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! The game I'm working requires enemies to use abilities as well as players so I think I'm going to go with static methods that require a few character specific inputs, but there could be issues with that that I haven't thought of yet so I might end up using a similar system. I hope your game goes well!

Comment: Thank you for advice. FYI I will be modifying my Effect system a bit, each character will have an EffectHandler component which will be in charge of managing the effects. This will make it much easier to control effect stacking and all. I can also just pass a GameObject to my AddToHandler() method of my Effects and have the effect register itself if GetComponent<EffectHandler>() is not null. I'm on the Unity forum and Answer under the same name if you would like to discuss design of other features.